# Is it possible to deny access to built in sql functions such as CONNECTIONPROPERTY and CURRENT_USER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to block authorization to built-in SQL Server functions that provide potential sensitive information of the DB Server.

e.g

- ConnectionProperty('net_transport')
- DB_NAME()
- APP_NAME()
- CURRENT_USER

Comment: Question belongs to https://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

No.

Only permissions from

```
SELECT *
FROM fn_builtin_permissions(default)
```

are accessible.

If you don't want users to execute those functions, a user should access DB through application (with app login/password that user doesn't know), so application controls what user executes.

Answer (score 1):

If a user is denied the permission VIEW ANY DATABASE, he should only be able to see the master, tempdb, and databases he owns.

However, the function `db_name()` still returns a value for databases he should not see. Since database ids are low integers it's a piece of cake to list all databases on a server. Note that database names may include sensitive information like customer names.

The same issue exists with `db_id()`.

It appears that this issue exists in all versions from SQL 2005 and on.